# Using SD card as external storage in Beaglebone Black Debian 8.7

Tags: sd-card, beagleboneblack

I had been working a while with my BBB and decided to update to last image, so I followed the guide on the Beagleboard.org site, I succeeded and now have the Debian 8.7 2017-03-19 image working just fine. However, before the update I had that same SD card as extra storage and now every time I put it into the BBB it flashes, so I would like to have that same SD card as extra storage as before.

Doing some research I read it was needed to have a uEnv.txt file with the following lines in the SD card:

```
mmcdev=1
bootpart=1:2  
mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk1p2 ro  
optargs=quiet
```

I'm newbie at this so I don't really know how to do so and the information I have found is not that explanatory. I would really aprecciate some help in doing this so I can start making more interesting applications. Thanks.

Comment: So, in order to summarize, you downloaded an image, put it on the SD-card and used this image to flash you internal eMMC on you BBB. But the problem is now that every time you boot the BBB with the SD-card mounted, it automatically re-flashes the board ?  If that is the case simply re-partition (e.g. use fdisk) and reformat (e.g. mkfs.ext4) the SD-card. If this is not the case, perhaps you can provide a pointer to the guide you followed.

Comment: It would be the first case, as I said I followed this guide: [link](http://beagleboard.org/getting-started#update)

Now the question would be how to do the re-partition since I can't power-up the BBB  with the SD mounted and not reflash. In the /boot/uEnv.txt file is commented the line that allows the automatic reflash, as far as I understand
##enable Generic eMMC Flasher:
##make sure, these tools are installed: dosfstools rsync
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh

Comment: Take the SD out and boot the unit  and attach it after boot? Our put the SD in your regular PC and partition/format it there.

Answer (score 1):

So in order to update the card image it is necessary to follow the steps shown in the beaglebord webpage: [software updates](http://beagleboard.org/Support/BoneScript/updates/) but only until the eighth step so the BBB boot off from the SD card, step nine is to program the onboard flash with the last image to boot off from there (the SD card will have to be unmounted).

Now that the BBB is booted off of the SD card, in Windows, if the df command is typed we would see this

`debian@beaglebone:~$ df -k --human
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs            98M  2.9M   95M   3% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p1  3.3G  2.8G  295M  91% /
tmpfs           245M  4.0K  245M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           245M     0  245M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000`

so that we know the file system is in the SD card, then running fsdisk command will extend the SD card partition for us to have the complete space in the SD card for the our applications.

Now the BBB is booted off of the SD card and also having that same SD card as available storage.